# Socket in TI C2000

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, microcontroller, texas-instruments

Can I use socket api in c2000 processor from texas instrument like f28388d with a cortex m4 and library lwip ?

I try to acctivate lwip socket with `#define LWIP_SOCKET 1` but i get many compilation error.

Does anyone have an example configuration for this device?